# Getting error Cross-thread operation when using Timer class

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winform application, and I am satisfied with what it does. I want to retrieve the latest data from the database every 15 minutes and display it in a DataGridView.

I added a Timer class. Once 15 minutes has elapsed, I can call the method that retrieves and displays the data. I received error (see the screenshot attached).

What am I doing wrong here?

Below is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      StartTimer();
    }

    private void RetrieveData()
    {

      DataTable table = new DataTable();
      table.Rows.Add(woStatus, dateReceived, dateApprovedFormatted, binNo, ppNo, woNo, daysDifference);

      dataGridViewMain.DataSource = table;
      dataGridViewMain.Sort(dataGridViewMain.Columns["Days in the shop"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
    }

    private void StartTimer()
    {
      aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000); // 10secs
      aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
      RetrieveData();
      aTimer.Start();
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
      aTimer.Stop();
      aTimer.Dispose();
      StartTimer();
    }
}
```

Comment: "see the screenshot attached" - I see none, but I don't think we need it

Comment: shouldn't `RetrieveData` be executed in `OnTimedEvent` ?

Comment: This kind of polling can be done, but really shouldn't be done. You should receive a notification when the DB is updated and then query the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`System.Timers.Timer` fires back on a random worker thread, **not** the UI thread. So when the code goes into `RetrieveData` (via `OnTimedEvent` then `StartTimer`) it is on the wrong thread. You could use `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {...})` to get to the right thread, but it is probably simpler just to use the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` component instead, since that automatically (via sync-context) fires on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know there is a Timer component in Windows.Forms.
I found this article very helpful http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any screenshot, but if your getting a cross-thread exception, I'd suspect its because you call the RetreiveData() within the StartTimer() method that's called *on the timer thread* when it elapses. You need to ensure that code affecting the UI is executed on the same thread as the UI, or you will get these kinds of exceptions. Take a look at the methods `InvokeRequired()` and Control.Invoke() that are provided to ensure method calls affecting the UI are done following a context switch back to the UI thread.